# In an HTML select is it possible to have the dropdown begin scrolled down to a certain option?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select with ages 13 - 99 for options with a default placeholder value of "Select an age".  I would like to keep this option so just making option 18 "selected" will not work. I would like when the dropdown is focused to begin with the list scrolled to where 18 is at the top of the list and if you want to get to 13-17 you would have to scroll up.

Comment: You could create a click event on the select and write some javascript that sets the value to the desired index. In angular this would be quite easy not sure if you're using a framework or plain js?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this :
https://jsfiddle.net/43ja2geu/4/ ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select name="ageDropDown"  id="ageDropDown"
      onFocus="document.getElementById('ageDropDown').value = 18;"
      >

</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var startingval = 13
  var maxval = 99
  var dropdownid = "ageDropDown" //change me to whatever id you use
  var mydropdown = document.getElementById(dropdownid);

  //build dropdown list
  for(i=startingval;i<=maxval;i++) {
    var val=i
    mydropdown.options.length+=1;
    rval=val;
    mydropdown.options[i- startingval].text= i ;
    mydropdown.options[i- startingval].value=rval;
  }
  mydropdown.options.length--;
  //Make sure the first element is "select an age"
  var firstoption = document.createElement("option");
  firstoption.text = "Select an age";
  firstoption.value = 0;
  //Add selector to first index
  mydropdown.options.add(firstoption,mydropdown.options[0])
  //Set index to 0
  mydropdown.value = 0;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```